# Missing files in SDK Manager, no emulator unable to access google downloads

Tags: eclipse, windows, sdk, adt, android-virtual-device

Help please,

I downloaded the Eclipse & SDK bundle, followed the google instructions, when I loaded eclipse and wrote the simple Hello world application all was fine.  I closed and then tried to run a virtual machine AVD.

The options populated for devices but state there is no system image.

I followed instructions which suggested it would show in SDK manager but it doesn't and each of the SDK Manager screenshots I've seen online seem to have much more content.

Then comes the problem that it doesn't fetch everything, for example I get the following:

**Failed to fetch URL http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml, reason: Connection to http://dl-ssl.google.com refused**

I tried putting proxy as www.google.com:80 and that didn't work

Also tried manually downloading files but SDK manager doesn't pick them up, there is also no Android folder created in program files, So I manually added one and placed the ARM system image file in there, no luck and tried placing it loads of other folders and reloaded SDK manager thinking it was a core part for the AVD process.

What am I doing wrong and why is this so exceptionally complicated?  Can I not simply have a manual resource download and import them into SDK manager?

Answer (score 0):

The same issue i was facing too, which resolved by adding few old API's of Android.
i have installed `Android 4.4.2(API 19), Android 4.3(API 18)` and `Android 4.2.2(API 17)` with `Android L(API 20)` 
and it worked. 
[image: It worked for me]

it worked for me, hopefully it will work for you as well.

Comment: Where is the correct place to download the API and what is the correct process for manual installation?

Comment: open the `SDK Manager` you will find the packages you have already installed.

Comment: This is the problem Abdul, the SDK Manager will not download anything so I have to go and manually download but trying to find the correct files and instructions.  p.s. how do I upload graphics to stackoverflow?

Comment: I have a resolution, it's because I'm behind a corporate firewall which was the reason it would not connect.  The proxy settings in the system were autofiled in a dat file so I ran that URL and located the proxies we use, updated SDK Manager and we're good to go!

Comment: @JohnTurner i'm glad to hear that. you also can get instructions from [link]http://www.mybringback.com/tutorial-series/362/android-getting-started-tutorial/
please mark the answer if you resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have a resolution, it's because I'm behind a corporate firewall which was the reason it would not connect. The proxy settings in the system were autofiled in a dat file so I ran that URL and located the proxies we use, updated SDK Manager and we're good to go!